# How to get array collect on laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I want to get the array on my row table and I'm using this controller

**controller.php**

```
public function editView($crewprogrammemoid){
    $transactionmemo = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select("select * from transaction_crewprogrammemo where crewprogrammemo_id = '?' ", [$crewprogrammemoid]);
    dump(collect($transactionmemo));
}
```

I don't know why but I got an empty array,my array should be there but I got nothing.

[image]

I test in on my SQL Server and I got the data, but when I test it on my controller thats empty array what I got. How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you try just checking youre able to connect correctly? could you try running the following inside tinker ```DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->getDatabaseName();``` also double check that you are connected to the correct database... sqlsrv2 suggests you have multiple database connections, ensure that they are configured correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `->get()` in the end of your query.

Here is a working example:

```
public function editView($crewprogrammemoid){
    $transactionmemo = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')
                         ->table('transaction_crewprogrammemo')
                         ->select('*')
                         ->where('crewprogrammemo_id', '=', $crewprogrammemoid)
                         ->get();

    dump(collect($transactionmemo));
}
```

Comment: DB is query builder not eloquent

Comment: there is a difference between DB::table() and DB::select(), DB::select() calls Illuminate\Database\Connection::select() (returns array) whilst DB::table() returns an instance of \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder which has access to get(). Chaining get to the query in the question would not have resolved the issue. However your amended post allows access to the get() method through the use of the table method, which changes which select() method is being called